# Github Project in Eclipse is not shown as JavaProject

Tags: java, eclipse, github, repository

I exported my Project to Github and checked it out in eclipse. This process worked - however it seems like eclipse does not recognize my.java files as javacode. It does not try to compile anything.
I do have a .project file and a .classpath file in the repository. Why doesn't it work. //reference removed

This is how it currently looks like. I am not sure whats causing this problem, but it might be that i got the main folder as project and the actual project inside this folder (nested). How can I fix this if this is the problem?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to commit your folder structure starting from :

```
/DragonsEdgeRefactored/
```

Since your project is already a Git repo, you can move the contents accordingly and commit the changes accordingly. I recommend using a GUI Git client like SourceTree or GitKraken.

Comment: Okay I actually just deleted the old repository and replaced it - seems to work now - Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You Should not check-in `.project`, `.classpath` files and `.settings` folder. As eclipse will only generate these files for you.

Try deleting these files from your git repository and then again clone it , it should work.

let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is a good way too fix bugs. Didn't fix mine but thank you for the answer :)